# AWS Cognito and AWS Api Gateway authorizations of users application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for authentication related to my application. Because I am also using AWS Api Gateway to consume Lambdas in my application, I need to set security levels on the Gateway.

In my application there will be many users, and in turn, there will be different roles (such as admin, marketing, management, etc). It should be noted that these users are application users, but not AWS IAM users.

I created several groups of AWS Cognito users, and in turn, I have several users in those groups. For example, users of the admin group can enter any exposed api. The marketing ones can only list a few things, but they cannot access the APIs to create, for example.

I would like to know how I can do to make Api Gateway allow or deny access to certain application users, but based on the AWS Cognito user pool.

PS: I have dealt with IAM roles in these groups, I have dealt with federated identities, but I don't know if I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Create OAuth scope for your user pool in AWS Cognito. Cognito->User Pool->App Integration->Resource server.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html

Step2: In AWS API Gateway use Authorisation as your AWS Cognito user pool and use the OAuth Scopes to set the resource servers that the user pool has access to.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html

For example your admin group will probably will have access to all the resource servers but your marketing group may have restricted access. So, if someone from your marketing group makes request to the API gateway and if he does not have access to a particular resource server they will get a 403 response.  Hope this helps.

Comment: When I define a scope on the resource server, that scope does apply to all users in the user pool, regardless of the role each one has?


How do I define for example that the admin user group will have access to all resources, and the marketing group will only have no more reading resources?

Comment: @DanielZapata Did you got a way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cognito User Pools, and groups, in combination with Cognito Identity Pools to provide fine grained, role based access control.

[This AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/) gives a detailed tutorial on how to set up fine grained role based access control using Cognito User Pools and Cognito Identity pools. It uses DynamoDB and S3 as examples, but you can apply the same principals to control access to almost any AWS service.

Comment: Regarding the federated identities of Cognito I have a question. The idea is that an application user logs in and can save users through the Front End of the application, but the idea is not that he can have temporary credentials to access directly Amazon  services, and see tables of a database, no!. That is mainly my confusion, Federal Identities gives me temporary credentials but so that I can access the Amazon console?, Or can I use it for a user to be validated if he can consume an Api Gateway endpoint or he would be denied.

Comment: What I need is simply to allow or deny that an application user through the Front End can enter an Api Gateway endpoint. For example, that Front End user is allowed to save users, but is denied deleting users. All this without directly entering the Amazon Web Services console, since they are only application users.

Comment: The way you are obtaining credentials will not grant console access.  In the tutorial you created a policy that allows or deny’s API gateway access. This policy is attached to the role that is assumed by members of the Cognito group. When the user logs in to your app, Cognito will assume the role associated with their group return access credentials; an AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey, and SessionToken. The app should then use these credentials to access API gateway, and the user will then be allowed or denied access as per the role that was assumed.

Comment: I did it the way you are telling me, but the problem I have, for example, is that from Postman I access the Api Gateway endpoint after logging in (with the token Id), and it allows me to enter the endpoint. I denied this endpoint in the role policy of the user group in which that user is. Below I will put how I am doing the role, so please check below in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below I show how I have parameterized everything in cognito:

1. I have a group of users in cognito.
2. I have a user assigned to that group in code.
3. The role of the group is as follows, which denies all access to api gateway:

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Effect": "Deny",
               "Action": [
                   "execute-api:Invoke"
               ],
               "Resource": "*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
4. I created an Identity Pool in cognito, which receives Amazon Cógnito, and I selected "choose a role from a token" and then "Deny".

However, when I log in from postman and get the id of the token, and then access with said data pointing from postman to an Api Gateway URL, all the data of that endpoint is returned, which is not correct, since I denied it the access.

Comment: Use `arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*` for the resource.  Make sure this policy is attached to the group the user is in.

Comment: @hephalump enter what you told me in the policy, but it still gives me access to that user, who should not enter the Api Gateway. I have tried many more things and I do not know if I am doing something wrong, or really cognito does not validate the roles of the users entered. If by chance you want me to send you another screenshot or something additional you tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Cognito definitely supports this. I’m not sure what the issue is, but you are certainly doing something incorrectly... AWS has tutorials specifically for this and we use this same strategy to control access to our API’s and it works perfectly.

Comment: I am using in the api gateway cognito authorizer. I don't know then if AWS_IAM should be used as an authorizer. Regarding Amazon documentation, it has been a bit complex to understand.

Comment: If you’re using the Cognito authorizer on API gateway then use the ID Token as the authorization header.